# Setting properties in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, properties

How can I manually add my own specific properties (user specific properties) to a project in Eclipse?

Like when Android was developed, they added some user specific properties or same as like `ANTLR`. After these were developed, we use the properties in our project to create Android project etc..

I am new to Eclipse and working on it. I have some plugins, I need to make a property in project that ask for some window where I can locate my file to choose and perform action like running those selected file.

Comment: That's a very descriptive question title you have there.

Comment: I was going to edit the title but I'll leave it as is so your comment makes more sense :)

Comment: *"I'll leave it as is.."*  I'll change it.  Those who are curious, can check the edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what do you mean. 
If you are asking about command line parameters when you are running your program use Run menu, then Run/Debug Configuration, choose tab "Arguments" and configure what you need.

If you are about environment variables available for project open the project properties dialog and push "Add Variable" button at the right.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I want to add self properties like when i select a project and then right click on it --->properties , there are options like Resources, Builders, WikiText etc. I want to make my own property say "ABC", then after this i need to add some button and text area which selects some particular file. I heard that IProjectNature will be used. But no idea.. Please let me know....

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried the method you mentioned. Actually my work is to define some properties like fetching of a file from a local machine by selecting an address or path. So i need to define a manual property in project say "ABC", so that when it is selected, it asks for a pth to select that file ! Automatically some dialog box should be opened to select path of the file or directly enter some path in the dialog box.

Comment: i have made a preference page and i am trying to fetch a file from preference page and trying  to run it using ProcessBuider.

the link of question is--- 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842700/java-how-to-use-processbuilder-to-access-path-from-preference-page-and-run-pris